# Send image file from html to Flask and save it in my system

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, flask

I am developing a webpage on uploading blogs with image cover. I want to upload image files from HTML page to flask and save it in my system. I have tried the code to do it but everytime I run the code , it shows me 500 Internal server error. Can anyone help me with that.

This is my html file - addblog.html

```
  <form action="/addblog" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div>
      <label for="image_uploads" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Cover Image (PNG, JPG)</label>
      <input type="file" id="image_uploads" name="image_uploads" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
      <p>No files currently selected for upload</p>
    </div><br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Content</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="content" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

This is my flask file.

```
    from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect
    from flask_session import Session
    from cs50 import SQL
    from tempfile import mkdtemp
    from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


    from helpers import login_required, convertToBinaryData, insertBLOB

    import sqlite3
    import os


    app = Flask(__name__)


    app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"] = "/home/ubuntu/FINAL_PROJECT/Blog_webapp/static/images/uploads"

    # Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
    app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
    app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
    app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
    Session(app)

    # Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
    db = SQL("sqlite:///blog.db")

    @app.route("/addblog", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def add():
        if request.method == "GET":
             return render_template("addblog.html")
        else:
             image2 = request.files["image_uploads"]
             image2.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image2.filename))
             content = request.form.get("content")

             print(image,content)
             insertBLOB(session["user_id"], image, content)

             return render_template("addblog.html")
```

This is the snippet of my terminal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF5sE.png)

Comment: You need to show us the complete traceback.

Comment: One quick tip always keep `debug=True` when you are developing you app so that you can see the errors.

Comment: I have added a traceback of the code, the debugger. But the problem is when the page loads when I hit the Submit button, it is not sending the data to POST action method. It is stuck, I am not able to identify the problem.